# Retrieve key, value pair in correct order with proper key

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am looking at an example from W3 schools, section convert JSON to Python

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```

I am trying to use key, value pair to print

```
import json

def emp_data(**args):
    emp= '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

    # parse x:
    jsonObject = json.loads(emp)


    # the result is a Python dictionary:
    for key in jsonObject:
        for value in jsonObject['name'], ['city'],['age']:
            print()
    print(key, jsonObject['name'], jsonObject['city'],jsonObject['age'])

emp_data()
```

The results are inconsistent and not printing all the keys.

```
age John New York 30
```

I tried separating them that did not fix the issue

```
print(key, jsonObject['name'])  

print(key, jsonObject['city'])  

print(key, jsonObject['age'])
```

I tried the `**args`, anything else I can try?

Comment: In your second snippet there's an obvious problem: you're printing three times for each key, and not using the key to access the value. In general, JSON objects/Python dictionaries aren't ordered data structures, consider `for key in ["name", "city", "age"]:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve but my understanding is that you're trying to print `key-value` pairs together. As @jonrsharpe mentioned, dictionaries aren't ordered structures and the issue is with the looping.

If you are wanting to print out the `key-value` pairs, you can do the following :

```
import json

def emp_data(**args):
   emp= '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

   # parse x:
   jsonObject = json.loads(emp)

   # the result is a Python dictionary:
   # As @Iluvatar mentioned, you can iterate over both key and value 

   for key,val in jsonObject.items():
      print key + ',' + str(jsonObject[key])
```

The result will be (in some order):

```
city, New York
age, 30
name, John
```

It might be a good idea to look at dictionaries again. I think you're missing something in your understanding.

Comment: You can iterate over both `for key, value in jsonObject.items()`